# Alinear contenido de celdas ItexSharp en C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Buen dia,

Estoy trabajando con C# con la librería de Itextsharp.

El cual al presionar un botón me crea un Pdf y dentro de el una pequeña tabla donde muestra los totales. Lo que quisiera saber como puedo alinear el contenido de las celdas de forma centrada, porque actualmente al inicializarlo lo muestra a lado izquierdo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que la alineación del contenido de las celdas sea en el centro.

Mi código para crear la tabla es el siguiente:

```
 var parrafo3 = new Paragraph("\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Total:", fuente);
                    document.Add(parrafo3);

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);

                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox19.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox20.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox21.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox22.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox23.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox24.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox25.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox26.Text, fuente3)));
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox27.Text, fuente3)));
                table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                //resto celdas

                document.Add(table);
```

Gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar las propiedades *HorizonalAlignment* y *VerticalAlignment* en el constructor de la clase *PdfCell* para centrado horizontal y vertical respectivamente.

```
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(textBox25.Text, fuente3)) { HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, VerticalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE });
```

Comment: ¡Excelente muchísimas gracias, un saludo!